# Storing of settings without database

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I need to store a list of columns/datatype pairs as app settings.
The amount of column/datatype pairs will be around 50 - 100, but could be more.
I cannot store these in a table due to client requirements.
There will be UI for the user to add/edit/delete from the list.

I was initially thinking of a delimited string stored in app.config.
Is there a practical limit to the size of string stored in a key in app.config?

Is there a better way?

[edit following sanjii's comment] is it possible to read/write an xml file with a dataset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would store them in a XML file. You could use XML Serialization or simply a DataSet.

```
DSUser ds = new DSUser();
ds.ReadXml(fileName);

ds.AcceptChanges();
ds.WriteXml(fileName);
```

Comment: +1 It seems like a perfect scenario for XML, though I prefer plain XML serialization to the DataSet option.

Comment: I'm with @santiiiii (hopefully there's enough i's there) but I've done this for some quick and dirty serialization and it worked great.

Comment: @callisto: It's just as easy as @Arthur posted above, where "filename" is the path to said XML file!

Comment: Yes - this was indeed a quick solution for a simple task. I just had to store up to 10 User. When it gets more complex I also prefer the XML Serialization method.

Answer (score 1):

Since these settings get loaded into memory when you application starts you are safe to store values in a config that would fit in memory.  In other words it is exactly as if you had hardcoded the string in C# (as far as memory utilization is concerned).

As an alternative, would your client obligations preclude the use of something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

> SQLite is a software library that
>   implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration,
>   transactional SQL database engine.
>   SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL
>   database engine in the world. The
>   source code for SQLite is in the
>   public domain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give up on app.config/app-settings just yet.

In order to store more-complex data structures in our application config we've taken two approaches: If the data structure we're trying to store can serialize to/from XML we store it as a string in the app-settings.  The alternative is implementing a `TypeConverter` that converts your data structure into a string and back.

Here's a cropped example:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FormStateConverter))]
public class FormState : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable {
   private Size _Size = Size.Empty;
   private Point _Location = Point.Empty;
   private FormWindowState _WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

   public FormState(Form form) { BindTo(form); }

   internal FormState(Size size, Point location, FormWindowState state) {
      _Size = size;
      _Location = location;
      _WindowState = state;
   }

   // lotsa other code...
}

internal class FormStateConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter {
   public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
      if (destinationType == typeof(string)) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return base.CanConvertFrom(context, destinationType);
      }
   }

   public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
      if (sourceType == typeof(string)) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
      }
   }

   // This converts a FormState to a string, we're just making a CSV string here...
   public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
      if (destinationType == typeof(String)) {
         FormState formState = (FormState)value;
         string converted = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", formState.Size.Height, formState.Size.Width,
            formState.Location.X, formState.Location.Y, formState.WindowState.ToString());
         return converted;
      }

      return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
   }

   // This converts a string back into a FormState instance.
   public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
      if (value is string) {
         string formStateString = (string)value;
         string[] parts = formStateString.Split(','); // split the CSV string

         if (parts != null && parts.Length == 5) { // attempt some error checking
            Size size = new Size();
            Point location = new Point();
            FormWindowState state = FormWindowState.Normal;

            int tmp;
            size.Height = (Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out tmp)) ? tmp : 0;
            size.Width = (Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out tmp)) ? tmp : 0;
            location.X = (Int32.TryParse(parts[2], out tmp)) ? tmp : 0;
            location.Y = (Int32.TryParse(parts[3], out tmp)) ? tmp : 0;

            if (string.Equals(parts[4], "maximized", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
               state = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            } else if (string.Equals(parts[4], "minimized", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
               state = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            } else {
               state = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }

            return new FormState(size, location, state);
         }
      }

      return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
   }
}
```

After implementing the type converter and attributing our `FormState` data type with the `TypeConverterAttribute`, the `FormState` type shows up in our Settings designer in Visual Studio: 
[image]

Comment: Note: It is possible to create custom appconfig sections that use more complex, hierarchical structures.

Comment: You're right.  Unfortunately I've only briefly ever read about that and haven't had a chance to implement anything. Got any good links that I should keep around for future reading?

Answer (score 0):

I also vote for XML based settings solution. You can find a nice example at [DotNetBlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) Source Code.

It's based on a basic Xml File , a singleton Settings Class and a SettingsProvider for read&write related stuff.
After proper implementation , all you have to do to reach settings is calling an instance of settings class ;

```
ApplicationSettings.Instance.Name = "MyApplicationName";
ApplicationSettings.Instance.Description = "It's an awesome application";
ApplicationSettings.Instance.Theme = "LoveThemeofMGS";
ApplicationSettings.Instance.Save();

testlabel.Text = ApplicationSettings.Instance.Name;
testlabel2.Text = ApplicationSettings.Instance.Description;
```

I personally use this for most of my Web Projects , it's an easy&clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Like most of the people who answered your question - I think that using some kind of XML based configuration will be the most convenient. I think that appconfig should be enough. It depend on you if Properties.Settings.Default is all you need, or maybe you need to use ConfigurationManager just for some more sophisticated tasks.

2) If you want to use typed dataset you should use xsd.exe tool (available in both: Visual Studio Packaga, and .Net Framework SDK). This little tool allows you to generate schema from xml file, and code or typed dataset from schema. Really useful.

3) If you consider using in memory database... maybe it will be much better to use Microsoft's SQL Compact Server instead of SQLite? (be aware that there are some [problems with dealing with date fields while using SQLite](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/01/27/FromSQLiteToSQLServerCompactEdition.aspx))